# How to avoid reboot after kernel crash Solaris 11 x86

Tags: solaris

I have a trouble with my hardware with Solaris 11 x86. I'll try to debug whats wrong, but I cannot find answer for my question:

I boot my Solaris using Grub, boot_archive loads for 100%, but after kernel crash and machine reboot completely. I need a way how to debug whats exactly wrong with my hardware, f.e. crash dump and freeze with no reboot at all.

Answer (score 0):

From console, run "mdb -K". This will trigger open mdb console, in which, just give ":c" (continue). Now if there is a crash, there won't be a reboot, the console will drop into mdb by printing the stack.

Comment: As I understood your answer, I need run mdb in bash shell. Actually, I only had grub; when I tried to boot Solaris, unfortunately, system was crashed on early stage, I never had access to the shell.